Nvidia cluster - RAM requirements for protein folding diffusion model
To preface, I am an undergrad machine learning intern working on a protein folding deep-learning project. I am new to this and the community.
I am currently working on a project for protein folding pathway prediction using the BERT Transformer to estimate a score function. The requirements for the model are two-fold: it should be able to take only initial 3d atomic coordinate data with corresponding atom types, and it should be able to generate a continuous-time protein folding pathway.
My thought-process is as follows: I will train a BERT on only the final conformations of protein structures, according to their atomic coordinates/types. This is essentially the giving the model a gauge for the distribution of final conformations across many mature proteins. Furthermore, since orientation/translation shouldn't affect the output of the final protein, besides rotating/translating the final result (equivariance), I needed to find some sort of equivariant representation, so I have embedded atomic coordinates into Fourier-Bessel features. This essentially maps 3d coordinates to 80d coordinates.
My problem is this: since I am dealing with sequences of >40,000 atoms, each (80+118 (one-hot encoded atom types))d, all in 32-bit float representations, I am obviously dealing with large RAM requirements. Especially considering that I want the max length of my BERT transformer to match the max length of an atomic sequence (i.e. no chunking).
Obviously, when I try running this on Google Colab (free version), my runtime crashes. Therefore, I wanted to ask the community for guidance:
**My institution (major tech company/industrial lab) has a very large cluster of Nvidia super chips. Could I just use these to fix the issue? Would this be the most optimal?
Is there a more efficient way to embed the sequence? Would chunking hurt the performance of my model?
Alternatives?**
Thanks!
I have tried representing each atom with an 80d equivariant representation + 118 one-hot encoded atom types. I am trying to use the transformer architecture, as opposed to GNNs, to perform this operation. My goal is to predict how an initial sequence of atom positions should fold according to a score-based diffusion model, with the score function estimated with the transformer.
